# Create an iOS apps to read data from mySQL and show image

Tags: php, mysql, xcode4, uiimageview, ipod

First of all, I create a database, I want to create an apps for my iPod, which can firstly download all of the image from my server, then my host computer (say my PC), choose the index of an image, say image01.png, then my apps detect the changing of mySQL (Thus my apps get the index row from mySQL), and image01.png will show on the iPod.

Can someone please suggest a way that I can write the apps? The php for my host computer is worked and tested perfectly, since I've already wrote a web version, which can do the same thing as the apps I mentioned above, but I have no idea on constructing the apps version.

I try to use a UIWebView and run the php of my web version, but it seems the WebView on my iPod sync too slow, (Thus, after my host computer chooses image01.png, my iPod show the image01.png after around 3 second) so that I want to create an apps version, to just show the png rather than a php.

And please suggest me the method to get all image from a specific folder on my server according to the folder name and image name.

Comment: You need a webservice. Output all the images of the database in json  format using php, and read the json data from your ios app.

Comment: Sorry, I just edit the question I want to ask, the images is not on the database, which is in my server only

Comment: From what I understood, for your app to detect changes in the mysql table on the fly, you will need push notifications. Please feel free to ask.

Comment: No, as I just want to show the new image that host computer shown, but not notify the iPod user about the changing, actually, I want the iPod user only can view the image but nothing else.

Comment: First, create a table containing two columns. first column should contain image name and second column containing boolean value (default 0). Output the table in json format and read the json data from your ios app. If you display image1.png in host computer, change the corresponding display column in the mysql table to 1. Refresh the app (webservice) and display the image whose display attribute equals 1 in the ios app.